# Hide browser address bar on BlackBerry OS6

Tags: html, mobile, blackberry, meta-tags, address-bar

I'm currently developing HTML 5 mobile web apps. If you add such an app to your homescreen on an iPhone, it pretty much looks like a native app since I am able to hide the mobile safari's address bar. This can be achieved by using some meta-tags within my HTML code.

Now I was wondering if hiding the address bar is also possible on the Blackberry OS 6? Does anyone have an idea if and how this could be achieved? Is there a Blackberry-specific meta-tag?

Answer (score 1):

There is no meta tag available for BlackBerry.
Try to use the `window.scrollTo (0,1)` function while loading the content into the browser.